# Can I restrict the access of my Google Apps Script Web App to a single Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: security, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, godot4

I'm following [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/jeg0boRWdxM?t=527) to connect a Godot program to a single specific Google Sheet.

However, when I reach the point of deploying the Web App, I'm asked to authorise the app to access my account - with a warning from Google that this will let the Web App alter ANY data in my Google account.

I would prefer to give this web app as little access to my account as absolutely possible - indeed, my intention was for the app to only be able to access a single Sheet.

Does anybody know how to deploy an Apps Script program while restricting access to a single Google Spreadsheet?

Comment: Can you provide the setting of your Web Apps? Can you provide the value of `Execute as` and `Who has access to the app:`?

Comment: @Tanaike - I'm afraid I don't know where I would find these settings. I'm currently searching for them, but if you can provide advice on their location, it'd be very helpful!

Comment: @Tanaike - The code I'm using can be found on this page: https://github.com/amzker/Gsheet_Godot

Comment: Thank you for replying. About your question of `I'm afraid I don't know where I would find these settings. I'm currently searching for them, but if you can provide advice on their location, it'd be very helpful!`, in this case, you can see [this official document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploy_a_script_as_a_web_app)

Comment: @Tanaike , ah, I see. 'Execute as' is set to 'Me' and 'who has access to the app' is set to 'Anyone'. Honestly, this warning is giving me a deal of anxiety...! https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/542710527391170560/1149308732950458378/image.png

Comment: About `The code I'm using can be found on this page: github.com/amzker/Gsheet_Godot`, when I saw your script, it seems that your script is the stand alone type and you want to use a Spreadsheet from the standalone script? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: As far as I know, this script is contained within a Spreadsheet. Still learning here...

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that your issue was resolved. I'm glad about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the script deployed as "Web app" is [bound](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) to the spreadsheet, you can use the jsdoc [`@OnlyCurrentDoc`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization#manual_authorization_scopes_forand) to limit the permissions to 1 spreadsheet. You can also manually adjust the permissions/oauth scopes in the [manifest](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests).

Comment: Ah - so, just to be sure, I basically add the commented code,
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */
to the start of my script, and that should restrict the permissions to the bound spreadsheet? Appreciate the advice...!

Comment: @ReverendSpeed Yes  as long as the script is "bound"

Comment: The script is bound. I'll mark your answer correct tomorrow unless there's any further notes on this.